# jQuery event.target is_a_child_of(element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Given `element`, a variable containing a JavaScript object/DOM element, how do I determine if the `event.target` is an element inside `element` or not?

```
function(event){
   // assume that var element exists in this scope
   if(event.target == a_child_of(element))
      // do something
}


<div id="myDiv">
   <div class="innerDiv">
      <input type="text"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

If `element` is `myDiv`, an event occurring on the inner div or the input, or any other element that may exist inside `myDiv` should cause the statement to evaluate to true.

I imagine that I could use a recursive function to build an array of child elements and then check if the `event.target` is in the array, but I want to see if there's a simpler answer first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[jQuery to the rescue](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/):

```
if (jQuery.contains(element, e.target))
```

Answer (score 40):

You can also use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
if ($(element).has(e.target).length > 0){
//
}
```

Comment: Revisiting this question after running into a similar problem, it appears that SLaks answer only works for immediate children, whereas Musa's works for all descendants. If you want to check if the element clicked is contained inside the given parent at any level, this is the correct code to use. Both work for single level children, and SLaks's answer may be more efficient if you know there is only one level of children to check against.

Comment: Also if you want to check if "my event occured on element" don't forget to add `e.target != $(element)[0]` to the condition.