# Prototype.js event.target.id for child elements

Tags: events, onclick, prototypejs, hide

I want to hide a div when clicking somewhere else in the page. For this, I have:

```
$(document.body).observe('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.id != 'myDiv') {
        $('myDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

Works fine, the only problem is that inside this div I have other elements, and clicking them also closes #myDiv. I want it so that clicking anything inside this div won't trigger the hiding. After searching around, I found the answer here on how to do this with jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222263/548524. However, I can't seem to get this working in Prototype, and obviously has() is not valid here.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'up' function:

```
$(document.body).observe('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.id != 'myDiv' && !$(e.target.id).up('#myDiv')) {
        $('myDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand how it should work, but the above code throws an error: Cannot call method 'up' of null. Also tried with $(e.target.id).up()!= 'myDiv' but I get the same error, so not sure if there's something missing from the syntax or why it won't work.

Comment: In order to get the id for $(event.target).up(), I had to use $(event.target).up().readAttribute('id') Now it works, but .up() only selects the first ancestors.

Comment: seems like we added comments at the same time! Yes, you're right, it works perfectly now, thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.observe('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.findElement('#myDiv')) {
    $('myDiv').hide();
  }
});
```

1. You don't need `$(document.body)` - there is already [document-wide observe](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/)
2. There is a method to [find element from event](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/prototype/findElement/)